# can not access memory at address 0xc8

Tags: c++, c++11

I am writing a code to return data of a node in BST based on id.
below is my node class:

```
struct Node{
int id;
string data;
Node *left;
Node *right;
Node();
};
```

below is my node constructor: I defined id and data in addNode function

```
Node :: Node(){
this->left = nullptr;
this->right = nullptr;
}
```

below is my BST class:

```
class BST{
private:
Node * root = nullptr;
void setRoot(Node *);
Node* getRoot();
public:
Node *addNode(BST *, int);//helper function
Node *addNode(Node *,int);
string getEntry(BST*,int);//helper function
string getEntry(Node*,int);
}
```

below is my helper functions:

```
Node *BST::addNode(BST *bst, int val){
addNode(bst->getRoot(),val);
}

string BST::getEntry(BST* bst,int id){
getEntry(bst->getRoot(),id);
}
```

below is my addNode class:

```
Node* BST::addNode(Node* root, int val) {
Node *newNode = new Node();
newNode->id = val;
newNode->data = "Number " + to_string(val);
if (root == nullptr) {
    if (getRoot() == nullptr){
        setRoot(newNode);
    }
    setCount(getCount()+1);
    return newNode;
}
if (root->id > val) {
    root->left = addNode(root->left, val);
} else {
    root->right = addNode(root->right, val);
}
return root;
}
```

below is my getEntry class:

```
string BST::getEntry(Node *base,int id) {
if (base == nullptr){
    return "";
}
if (base->id == id){
    cout<<base->data<<endl;
    return base->data;
}
getEntry(base->left,id);
getEntry(base->right,id);
}
```

below are the nodes I passed in from main:

```
int main(){
BST *newBst = new BST();
newBst->addNode(newBst,1);
newBst->addNode(newBst,2);
newBst->addNode(newBst,3);
newBst->addNode(newBst,2);
newBst->addNode(newBst,3);
newBst->addNode(newBst,5);
newBst->addNode(newBst,7);
newBst->addNode(newBst,10);

cout<<newBst->getEntry(newBst,5)<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

The code would compile but does not return anything, I tried to debug, at the "return base->data statement", there is an error "can not access memory at address 0xc8". What causes the problem and what can I do about it?

this is the warning I got when I debug the code.
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181509/discussion-on-question-by-lanlan-can-not-access-memory-at-address-0xc8).

Comment: How far through the code do you get? What's the tree structure that's already in place when this error occurs?

Comment: I've rollbacked your last edit: please find your solution in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52710058/revisions) and post it as an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (base->id != id){
    getEntry(base->left,id);
    getEntry(base->right,id);
}
```

As you are using a sorted tree, you know which of the right or left node you need to have a look at. Also, you need to return something:

```
if (base->id > val){
    return getEntry(base->left,id);
```

} 
    return getEntry(base->right,id);

But the design with `addNode` is very bad, you shouldn't have to pass the root twice!

Comment: that is becase I am not allowed to set getRoot to public and I want to use recursion.

Comment: and I tried to add return to both "getEntry", would compile, but still not returning anything.

Comment: I still don't understand. You can access `getRoot` from your method, you don't need to pass anything in the public API. Don't return both entries, write what I gave you and understand what the code is now doing, compare it to what you want and what you wrote. A book on algorithms in c++ would also be a good option  for you.